# Usage of articals. e.g. When do we use a singular noun on its own without an article?

Tags: articles, zero-article

2 questions.

### Q1. Earlier these days, I saw the usage of "Leader of ...", which is a countable noun without a preceding article. Is that grammatically correct?

What I found in [oxford guide to english grammar](https://www.uop.edu.jo/download/research/members/oxford_guide_to_english_grammar.pdf):

> A singular noun on its own • 167
>
> We use a singular noun on its own only in some special patterns.

However, further explanation is not given in that pdf.

Then I found another pdf: [esl article usage rules](https://www.untdallas.edu/sites/default/files/page_level2/jmd0413/pdf/esl_article_usage_rules.pdf). But I didn't find the usage of "Leader of ..." in it.

So, is the last pdf accurate?

### Q2. "a becoming humility"(article before uncountable noun) is OK.

[My answer to another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/503091/352751) referring to [A | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a):

> used before some uncountable nouns when you want to limit their
>   meaning in some way, such as when describing them more completely or
>   referring to one example of them:
>
> I only have a limited knowledge of Spanish.
>
> He has a great love of music.
>
> There was a fierceness in her voice.

But in the last pdf [esl article usage rules](https://www.untdallas.edu/sites/default/files/page_level2/jmd0413/pdf/esl_article_usage_rules.pdf), an article before "thing"(a countable noun) can be omitted:

> Rule 37: Use Ø when generalizing about abstract nouns.
>
> ex: Love is beautiful thing.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation given in the *Oxford Guide to English Grammar* ("*We use a singular noun on its own only in some special patterns"*) is not particularly useful. More helpful is the following extract from *Collins Cobuild English Guides 3: Articles* (p50) in the section called *Special Roles*:

> Some nouns can refer to a special, unique role held by a person in a
> particular situation (for example, a government or business). When
> they are used like this, you can leave out the definite article.
>
> - ...when he was President.
> - It was nearly 40 years before she became Queen.
> - ...Mr John Hume, leader of the Social and Democratic Labour
>   Party.

The Guide goes on to list numerous examples of 'special roles' (including *captain, chair, boss, treasurer, director, author*), and concludes:

> Note that when you are talking about a person rather than describing
> someone's role you need an article.
>
> - The President had issued a sympathetic reply.
> - The Queen then abandoned the project.

Since you have not included the sentence in which you saw the words *Leader of...*, it is not possible to say definitively if the definite article is needed or not.

Finally, a comment:  Your Q2 is best asked as a separate question.

Comment: You perfectly solved my 1st question. But they're just about usages of articles. Can you post the full rules of using articles in _Collins Cobuild English Guides_? Or can I find a full usage on the internet? Since the _esl article usage rules_ is not complete.

Comment: @SP999. The _Articles_ Guide has over 120 pages, so it is not possible to post the full rules. But you can always ask an 'articles' question on this site (or the _English Language Learners_ site), if you prefer not to buy the book.

Comment: Alright, I made [another question here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216284/a-becoming-humility-love-is-beautiful-thing). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SP999. The example sentence _Love is beautiful thing_ is not grammatical. It should be _Love is a beautiful thing_. The rule it is exemplifying refers to _love_, not _thing_.